# Break a string into parts, returning all characters

Tags: php, split, php-5.3, preg-split

I want to break a string according to the following rules:

1. all consecutive alpha-numeric chars, plus the dot (`.`) must be treated as one part
2. all other consecutive chars must be treated as one part
3. consecutive combinations of `1` and `2` must be treated as different parts
4. no whitespace must be returned

For example this string:

```
Method(hierarchy.of.properties) = ?
```

Should return this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Method
    [1] => (
    [2] => hierarchy.of.properties
    [3] => )
    [4] => =
    [5] => ?
)
```

I was unsuccessful with `preg_split()`, as AFAIK it cannot treat the pattern as an element to be returned.

Any idea for a *simple* way to do this?

Comment: I thought about something like `preg_split('/[^a-z0-9\.]+/i', ...)` but couldn't go much further for the reason mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all) over preg_split.

```
preg_match_all('/[\w|\.]+|[^\w\s]+/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Method
            [1] => (
            [2] => hierarchy.of.properties
            [3] => )
            [4] => =
            [5] => ?
        )

)
```

Comment: Makes sense, I was too focused on `preg_split()`! Your code works for me. Thank you.

Comment: Just a side note: beware that `\w` is locale-dependent, and might match accented chars as well. It's better to stick with `[a-z]` and keep the control over what's matched and what's not!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$matches = array();
$string = "Method(hierarchy.of.properties) = ?";
foreach(preg_split('/(12|[^a-zA-Z0-9.])/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $match) {
    if (trim($match) != '')
        $matches[] = $match;
}
```

I used a loop to remove all whitespace matches, since as far as I know there isn't a feature in preg_split() to that for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code breaks with several consecutive non-dot-and-alphanumeric chars: `==` gets split into `=` and `=`. I'll go with Glass Robot's code, which looks cleaner & stronger. Thanks anyway!